# Subtracting values from two data frames given same value in column

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I currently have two data frames with the same number of columns and column names. Two of the columns in both data frames are 'Time' and "Trip_ID'. In this case I want to subtract the Time values between both dataframes if the rows have the same Trip_ID.

Example -

```
Time   Trip_ID
15     X
20     Y
25     Z

Time   Trip_ID
35     Z
40     Y
65     X
```

I want to have a list of all of the differences in time which, in this case, would look like (50, 20, 10)

Comment: `df1.set_index('Trip_ID').sub(df2.set_index('Trip_ID')).reset_index()`

Comment: you can use @QuangHoang sol,  you can edit to keep df2 at left :)

Answer (score 0):

In one line:

```
(df2.set_index('Trip_ID')- df.set_index('Trip_ID')).squeeze().tolist()
```

Output:

```
Out[14]: [50, 20, 10]
```